# Spring mvc REST API

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, веб-служба, rest

Подскажите, как лучше сделать REST API в SpringMVC приложении ?
Использовать Jersey RESTful web service framework или просто RESTful Framework ?
Не знаю, правильно ли я сформулировал вопрос, просто я видел несколько вариантов реализации API:

- с использованием аннотаций `@Path`, `@Post`, `@Get`.
- с использованием `@RestController`, `@ResponceBody`, `@ResponseEntity`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Аннотации `@Path`, `@Post`, `@Get` и некоторые другие входят в спецификацию [JAX-RS](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/).

`@RestController`, `@ResponceBody`, `@ResponseEntity` относятся к собственной реализации Spring-а в рамках Spring MVC.

Если в вашем проекте не используется Spring MVC или вы пишите standalone-приложение (не для сервлет-контейнера) - берите реализацию JAX-RS на свой вкус: Jersey, Apache CXF, RESTeasy.

Если же ваше приложение разворачивается в сервлет-контейнере и уже использует Spring MVC, вероятно вам будет удобно работать в его рамках.